# how to delete last 10 charecters in XML file using PHP and then add some text?

Tags: php, xml

this is my PHP Code which takes the data from a form:

```
<?php
$itemPath         = $_REQUEST['itemPath'];
$title          = $_REQUEST['title'];
$description1    = $_REQUEST['description1'];
$description2    = $_REQUEST['description2'];
$description3    = $_REQUEST['description3'];
$price          = $_REQUEST['price'];
$note            = $_REQUEST['note'];

$xmlfile = "women.xml";
$file = fopen($xmlfile,"r+");
$handle = "</items>";
$newphrase = $file;
//rewind($handle);
$newphrase = str_replace($handle, "", $newphrase);
fwrite($file, $newphrase);
fclose($file);

$file = fopen($xmlfile,"a+");
fwrite($file, "\n<item path='women/".$itemPath.".jpg' type = 'bitmapfile'>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<title>".$title."</title>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<description1>".$description1."</description1>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<description2>".$description2."</description2>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<description3>".$description3."</description3>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<description3>".$description3."</description3>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<price>".$price."</price>\n");
fwrite($file, "\t<note>" . $note . "</note>\n");
fwrite($file, "</item>\n");
fwrite($file,"</items>");
fclose($file);
?>
```

and here is the XML:

```
<items id = "items">
<item path = "women/3.jpg"  type = "bitmapfile">
<title>No.3</title>
<description1>Flowers</description1>
<description2>50 ml</description2>
<description3>pure</description3>
<price>35</price>
<note></note>
</item>

<item path = "women/6.jpg" type = "bitmapfile">
<title>Trish McEvoy No.6</title>
<description1>Trish McEvoy No. 6 Mandarin & Ginger </description1>
<description2>50 ml / 1.7 fl oz Eau de Toilette</description2>
<description3>Authenticity: 100% Guaranteed</description3>
<price>35</price>
<note></note>
</item>

</items>
```

what is wrong with my PHP code and how could i delete the last  and insert a new item in the XML file then add  at the end???

should i use in PHP 
     $file = fopen($xmlfile,"a+");
OR
     $file = fopen($xmlfile,"r+");

Comment: This is not the way you should working with XML.

Comment: this is the first time to use XML, i can add the the end of the file by using a or a+, but i should insert the new item before the </items> tag. please help

Answer (score 0):

```
$newItem = '<item>test</item>';

echo str_replace('</items>', $newItem.'</items>', file_get_contents($file));
```

Comment: what is the $xmlString?? the new $newItem should be the new product info right?? what about the $xmlString? and i want to add the new item after the old items.

Comment: I changed to code, the xmlString was meant to contain the XML.

Comment: $newItem = "<item>test</item>";

echo str_replace("</items>", $newItem."</items>", file_get_contents($file));

i have changed the single quot with double quot, and when i press on submit this error became "Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\desiered\women_add.php on line 15"  

and with $file = fopen($xmlfile,"r+"); i should use (
 r+ OR w+ OR a+ )

Comment: $file is the filename! just pass the path to the file!

Answer (score 0):

This way you delete last 10 character...

```
$xml = "...";
$xml = substr($xml, 0, strlen($xml)-10);
```

But this is not the way as "fabrik" said.

Comment: Warning: strlen() expects parameter 1 to be string, resource given in C:\wamp\www\mokaiefat\women_add.php on line 13